# React-router error: super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react-router (https://github.com/rackt/react-router). I included it after react like this:

```
<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactrouter/0.13.2/ReactRouter.js"></script>
```

I got an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

What did I do wrong?

Comment: have you tried with a newer build of React? It's at `0.13.1` now.

Comment: Who throws the error? react, react-router, other javascript code? And in which browser are you seeing the error?

Comment: It was react-router on latest version of Chrome browser.

Comment: I updated React to 0.13.1, and the problem was gone. Thanks WiredPrairie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I sloved the issue by upgrading react version to 0.13.3

```
npm install react@0.13.3
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I also had to change my react-router to 0.13.3.

Comment: I have the 0.14.7 and I've got such issue

Comment: @Edward: did u update react router  also to latest version?

Answer (score 114):

Though this has been resolved, I am posting a solution since I had a similar problem.  Hopefully it will be helpful to someone else.

I wasn't using React Router.  I was using React with Webpack, with Babel as loader.  I was getting the same error as stated by JustWonder.

I was using ES6 classes.  Turns out, I had typed

```
class App extends React.component {...}
```

Changing `React.component` to `React.Component` (upper-case 'C') solved the problem for me.

Comment: This damn thing solves my problem too. Seems like you will get that error if you misspelled "React.Component". And it's case sensitive so watch for it guys.

Comment: I'd put Components instead of Component

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered another scenario where this may occur.

I had `v0.13.x` as a direct dependency, and one of my dependencies had `v0.12.x` - so two copies of React were included in my bundle. This meant components using ES6 classes were attempting to `extend` a non-existent `React.Component` (they were getting the `v0.12.x` of React).

I diagnosed this issue by looking how many copies of react were in my `node_modules`:

```
npm ls | grep react@
```

Which gave me the following result:

```
├── react@0.13.3
│ └── react@0.12.2
```

The `-C` option for `grep` allows you to see surrounding lines, so I re-ran:

```
npm ls | grep react@0.12.2 -C 5
```

The surrounding text allowed me to identify the offending package.